# Delete all .py files which dont have a corresponding .pyc file

Tags: python

We want to ship a smaller chunk of python distribution to the customer.
So, the idea here is to use the existing python distribution in our application and to do all possible tests. This will make sure that the **.pyc** files are created only for those **.py** files which are being used by our application. Rest all are unnecessary and should be deleted.

Whats the easiest way in python to do this self cleanup? 
I can also use default python installation and pass our python dist to it for cleanup.

Comment: 1. Is "doing all possible tests to ensure that. pyc files are created" part of the problem to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python script that should do the job, but I'd be curious to know if Python will still work after running it.

```
import os

pyc_files = []
py_files = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.pyc'):
            pyc_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        elif filename.endswith('.py'):
            py_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for py_file in py_files:
    if py_file + 'c' not in pyc_files:
        os.remove(py_file)
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to delete the .pyc files.

Comment: This deletes the *.pyc files. This is not what the question meant.

Comment: Sorry about the misread, but you should understand the confusion. If you delete all .py files that don't have a corresponding .pyc, I'm pretty sure python is gonna break.

Comment: Well I can pass in a copy of the  distribution to the original installation of python in that case.

Comment: Well, I made you a script that should do the job. I'd be interested to hear back how it goes.

Comment: Maybe it's necessary to delete any existing .pyc files before doing those tests that ensure their creation (to have a clean start).

Comment: Well i did not do the self cleanup method and used my default install to cleanup the " 64 bit distribution" that i roll out to the customers. It deletes them all right. Thanks!