# Delete XML file which does not have corresponding JPG file

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I have a folder which contains images and XML files with the same names

So an example will be

```
A.jpg A.xml
B.jpg B.xml
C.jpg C.xml
```

and so on

I want to delete XML files which do not have their corresponding jpg files

All files are in the same folder.

OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: What did you try? How did your efforts fail?

Comment: I am newbie with bash scripting, so what I did was use the GUI. I zoomed in till can see only the xml and jpg together. but there are 1000+ images so manually it's going to take a lot of time

Comment: Also I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489948/delete-all-py-files-which-dont-have-a-corresponding-pyc-file

Comment: But it does opposite of what it is supposed to

Comment: do you have nested directory or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically you can solve your problem in this way no matter using command line or any scripting language

#### first find and separate list of `xml` file and `jpg`

```
find -name \*.xml | sed 's/\.xml//g' > list-xml
find -name \*.jpg | sed 's/\.jpg//g' > list-jpg
```

we did not care about files extensions: `xml` or `jpg` just name of files

#### scond sort both lists and unique them, those that are **1** are single file that do not have their corresponding `xml` or `jpg`

```
cat list-xml list-jpg | sort | uniq -c | grep 1
```

#### third check the output

which is name of a file without `xml` or `jpg` and if it is **xml** we should remove it

---

example even if it is recursive

```
tree .
├── one
│   ├── A.jpg
│   ├── A.xml
│   ├── B.jpg
│   ├── B.xml
│   ├── C.jpg
│   ├── C.xml
│   └── D.xml      # this one is a single one
├── three
│   ├── A.jpg
│   ├── A.xml
│   ├── B.jpg
│   ├── B.xml
│   ├── C.jpg
│   └── C.xml
└── two
    ├── A.jpg
    ├── A.xml
    ├── B.jpg
    ├── B.xml
    ├── C.jpg
    └── C.xml
```

[image]

now that our output is:

```
cat list-xml list-jpg | sort | uniq -c | grep 1
      1 ./one/D
```

we know that we should delete this file **if it is an xml** one. So simple try

```
rm -f ./one/D.xml
```

**how about more than one files?**

Well. Store the list of output; add `xml` at the end of all and then delete all file in the list. Like this if you stored the output in a file named **result**

```
perl -lne 's/ +\d//g && print "$_.xml"' result
```

which gives you:

```
./one/D.xml
```

you can use **perl** to delete them directly or the better is to store them so you can have a list of what you have / want to delete.

---

Also you can solve it very simpl but it is a little bit tricky.
Think about your need carefully:

> I want to delete XML files which do not have their corresponding jpg files

So you need to remove `xml` files that we do not have a file with the same name but in `jpg` format, right?

#### first list of all `xml` files

```
find -name \*.xml > all-xml
```

#### check if the file exists but with `jpg` format?

```
$ perl -lne 's/\.xml$/.jpg/g && print -e  $_' all-xml 
1
1
1
1
1
         # this file does not exist
1
1
1
1
$ # it means that xml file exists but it has no corresponding jpg file
$ # we can see name of this file
$ # here with perl we see if it exists -e $_ do nothing
$ # otherwise print the file
$ perl -lne 's/\.xml$/.jpg/g && -e  $_ || s/\.jpg/\.xml/ && print ' all-xml
./one/D.xml
```

that file that does not have a corresponding `jpg` is:

```
./one/D.xml
```

---

And you can do it in one line like so:

```
perl -MFile::Find -le 'find(sub{ ($_=$File::Find::name) && push(@xml,$_) }, "." ); END{ s/xml$/jpg/ && print -e $_ || (s/jpg$/xml/) &&  print $_ for @xml}'
1
./all-xml           # ./all.jpg does not exist, yes it is our file
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
./one/D.xml         # ./one/D.jpg does not exist so this file should be deleted 
1
1
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash and its [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for file in *.xml; do
  jpg="${file%.xml*}.jpg"      # if $file contains A.xml, $jpg is set with A.jpg 
  if [[ ! -e "$jpg" ]]; then   # true if $jpg does not exists
    echo rm -v "$file"
  fi
done
```

If output looks fine, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

this python code can help, you just need to edit the path variable.

```py
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

path = 'your path'

files = os.listdir(path)

for file in tqdm(files):
    filename, filetype = file.split('.')
    if filetype == 'xml':
        continue

    imgfile = os.path.join(path, file)
    xmlfile = os.path.join(path, filename + '.xml')
    if not os.path.exists(xmlfile):
        print('{} deleted.'.format(imgfile))
        os.remove(imgfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete all .jpg files that do not have a corresponding .xml file and all .xml files that do not have a corresponding .jpg file

```
   import os

files = os.listdir("training")
for i in files:
    for j in os.listdir("training/"+i):
        if (j.split(".")[0] + ".xml" not in os.listdir("training/"+i)) or (j.split(".")[0] + ".jpg" not in os.listdir("training/"+i)) :
        
            print(j)
            os.remove("training/"+i+"/"+j)
```